# Cakephp saving data without id

Tags: cakephp, model, save, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have a table which have no id field, and using a field 'app_no' as the primary-key.

Right now I have to do saving to this model/table... but there's no $id in the model and thus it fails.

Is there any method that I can do the saving with `Model->save()` without the `$id`?

Remarks: the table is shared with other projects, and so can't make any changes on the table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Model::updateAll()` instead. The first parameter takes the new values, the second parameter your conditions.

So you could do

```
$this->Model->updateAll(array("Model.value" => "'value'"),array("Model.name" => "name123"));
```

But be careful, unlike `save()`, this takes MySQL expressions.

Okay, at first this sounded like you did not have a primary key. If all you need is a differently named PK field, just do this in the Model:

```
public $primaryKey = 'app_no';
```

Or you could set the property straight on the Model object

```
$this->Model->primaryKey
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the primary key in your model like:

```
//Model 
var $primaryKey = 'app_no';
```

Then save will work the way you require.

Please check the "primaryKey" section using this link:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html

Comment: the primary key is set already. And the save only works for saving new record, but not saving existing records

Comment: I used this to access a table with no id field (i've created a hibrid wordpress that uses cake models and controllers) table usermeta uses umeta_id as a primarykey. var $primaryKey = 'umeta_id'; did it.  (to access a singular table used public $useTable = 'ry1k_usermeta';